# Inbox is showing "new answers" when there's only one answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, plurals

In my inbox, I'm seeing "new answers" when there's only one answer on the post:

[image]

Yes, this is a pluralization bug, but it's rather confusing. So can we please fixify it?

Comment: Really...pluralization bugs.

Comment: I _c know_ problem with fixing this; however, _their_ may be other _user's_ that disagree with it. ;)

Comment: @Servy Of course! Pluralization bugs are fun and they mean I couldn't find anything worse!

Comment: @SlyRaskal ... I hate you ... so much ... grrr

Comment: @Bart, haha, just doing my part to spread joy around MSO. Cheers!

Comment: It's called cropping.  You should try it.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Hehe, my evil plan of making people wonder what's behind it is working :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That S actually belonged somewhere else.  Yous guys should see it fixed in the next build.